# Calling delegate method from generic class

Tags: c#, class, generics, delegates

I would like to call MyDelegateMethod from SomeClass but I have no idea how to do it. I want my class to work for every delegate not juste only the one provided in the sample code.

thanks !

```
using System;

namespace SomeTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        public delegate int MyDelegate(string str);
        public static int MyDelegateMethod(string str) => str.Length;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new SomeClass<MyDelegate>(MyDelegateMethod);
            test.Test();

        } 
    }

    public class SomeClass<SomeDelegate> where SomeDelegate : class
    {
        SomeDelegate MyDelegateMethod;

        public SomeClass(SomeDelegate MyDelegateMethod) => this.MyDelegateMethod = MyDelegateMethod;
                                             /* this part of code fails */
        public void Test() => Console.WriteLine(MyDelegateMethod("Test"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the special case your provided you can use `Func<string, int>` instead of the delegate like this:

```
public class Program
{

    public static int MyDelegateMethod(string str) => str.Length;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new SomeClass(MyDelegateMethod);
        test.Test();

    }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    Func<string, int> MyDelegateMethod;

    public SomeClass(Func<string, int> MyDelegateMethod) => this.MyDelegateMethod = MyDelegateMethod;

    public void Test() => Console.WriteLine(MyDelegateMethod("Test"));
}
```

And you can generalize that for any single input/single output func like this:

```
public class Program
{

    public static int MyDelegateMethod(string str) => str.Length;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new SomeClass<string, int>(MyDelegateMethod);
        test.Test("Test");

    }
}

public class SomeClass<TIn, TOut>
{
    Func<TIn, TOut> MyDelegateMethod;

    public SomeClass(Func<TIn, TOut> MyDelegateMethod) => this.MyDelegateMethod = MyDelegateMethod;

    public void Test(TIn input) => Console.WriteLine(MyDelegateMethod(input));
}
```

Comment: It seems pretty good, thanks ! But how about making the class working for Func with X args ?

Comment: As you can see from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=netframework-4.8) `Func` has many variants with more parameters. Right now `SomeClass` is just a wrapper for `Func<...>` so you would have to wrap each variant respectively.

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks !